# Don't have the new 'Software' Store in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-center, 16.04

I finished installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS just now but I can't see the new 'Software' Store in it, I still have that old 'Ubuntu Software' Store. How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: Please add more details to your question like screenshots , version no of installed software package etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tipped the check box to download updates during install?
If not try to make an update.

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

But normaly it should be installed, except the case of a beta build

Comment: I've updated the full system already.